# Error installing LetsEncrypt SSL: (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am trying to install [`LetsEncrypt`](https://letsencrypt.org/) on my server (which I have root SSH access to), for `staging.dnslaude.com` - which is a publicly accessible domain, pointing to `213.212.81.89`.

The server is running `ubuntu 16.04`, and an `nginx` web-server. Below is the `nginx` config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name staging.dnslaude.com;

  root /path/to/webroot;

  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/self/signed/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.key;

  server_name staging.dnslaude.com;

  root /path/to/webroot;

  # ....

  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

You can see that the `nginx` config *appears* to work, as I have manually placed a file in the `acme-challenge` folder [here](http://staging.dnslaude.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test).

However, when I run the command:

```
letsencrypt certonly --webroot -w /path/to/webroot -d staging.dnslaude.com
```

It returns the following error:

> Failed authorization procedure. staging.dnslaude.com (http-01):
>   urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the
>   client to verify the domain :: Could not connect to
>   staging.dnslaude.com
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: staging.dnslaude.com    Type:   connection    Detail: Could
>   not connect to staging.dnslaude.com
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
>   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
>   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
>   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
>   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.

I followed the basic setup guide outlined [here](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-nginx), and have tried all sorts of configuration variations, such as those suggested [here](https://github.com/letsencrypt/acme-spec/issues/221). However, I cannot get past the above error - and cannot see anything in a log file to indicate the cause.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your nginx config looks correct.

On a hunch, I ran `nmap` against your domain (since you included it in your question); it would appear that you are currently filtering port 80, so there is no way for LetsEncrypt to connect externally and verify.

You'll need to make sure that port 80 is made externally accessible on the local firewall of the server in question (as well as any ACLs which might be in place on a vhost provider or similar).

Comment: Ahhhhh... OK, I realise what happened now. The server is part of a firewall policy that only white-lists certain IPs, such as the internal office's IP. So from my perspective, the server appeared to be working fine, but LetsEncrypt were obviously unable to get through the firewall to validate the host. (I do not have access to the firewall configuration, so was oblivious to this...)

Comment: Moral of the story, if anyone else lands here with the same issue: Try running `nmap` from a server *outside your local network*, to see if it's still visible.

Comment: Absolutely. Easy mistake to make, but a fairly big one! Glad I could point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you don't want/can't nmap from outside, just use http://isup.me to check if port 80 is answering or not.

Answer (score 2):

This error may also occur if you're redirecting the http-01 challenge from http to https. The .well-known/acme-challenge directory needs to be accessible via http on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

They obfuscate intentionally. I had the same 400 error and started down the rabbit hole with renewal again. The previous times there were different errors. Solution: Delete previous certificates from SSL for Free and uninstall expired certificate from server. (While expired certificate is still configured and active you will never get a new one) jar2